# Tenda 1024g Screw Type?

Tags: networking, switch, rack

Does anybody know the type of screw/clip nut I should use for my Tenda 1024g? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can contact the [manufacturer](http://www.tenda.cn/tendacn/product/show.aspx?productid=362) for "rackmount ears", if you don't have them. Otherwise, you may need to place the switch on a shelf...

[image]

Edit:

Since you have the rack ears, you need a [**cage nut**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cage_nut), which clips into the square hole and provides a threaded receptacle for a matching bolt.

See: [image]

Comment: Yeah, the ears are on, but how do I mount the ears to a square-hole rack?

Comment: See the update above.

Comment: But what size screw?

Comment: The screw and threading matches the cage nut. You would buy them together. They come in [different lengths and thread counts](http://www.racksolutions.com/rack-hardware.html).

Comment: But what size screw for my switch? Thanks!